# Connecting ESP32 to Google Cloud IoT Core (using Google Cloud IoT Device SDK and ESP-IDF)

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, esp32, google-cloud-iot

I am trying to send data from Google Cloud Firestore (via Google Cloud IoT Core) to an ESP32 device. I have followed [this guide](http://nilhcem.com/iot/cloud-iot-core-with-the-esp32-and-arduino), using the option of using Google approved way of Google Cloud IoT Device SDK and ESP-IDF. This is covered in [the linked Github readme](https://github.com/Nilhcem/esp32-cloud-iot-core-k8s/tree/master/03-esp32_bme280_ciotc_esp-idf).

I have installed both Cloud IoT Device SDK and ESP-IDF and have got the hello-world example of ESP-IDF working. But I get stuck when trying to configure wifi settings (under the heading "Compile time constants in the readme"). `make menuconfig` works when in the ESP-IDF project folder, e.g. the hello-world example, i.e. opens the menu. But I can't find the settings for Wifi ("WiFi SSID", "WiFI Password") or Google Cloud IoT Core ("Project ID", "Location", "Registry ID" and "Device ID"). Is it even in ESP-IDF where these settings are to be found?

I should add that I am not using BME280 sensor like in the guide, but am only wanting to make sure I get some kind of a connection between the device and Google Cloud at first.

I haven't done anything to get the ESP32 connected to wifi either, if this has something to do with it (not in the guide explicitly, so I thought it might work all the same).

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In order to see the settings for wifi you'll need to have a Kconfig file that has the variables in it. If you add the following code you should see the wifi settings in Menuconfig -> Example Configuration

```
menu "Example Configuration"

config ESP_WIFI_SSID
    string "WiFi SSID"
    default "myssid"
    help
    SSID (network name) for the example to connect to.

config ESP_WIFI_PASSWORD
    string "WiFi Password"
    default "mypassword"
    help
    WiFi password (WPA or WPA2) for the example to use.

endmenu
```